# error : ReportServerResources

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site, reportserver

error on site setting :

```
$Resources:ReportServerResources,ReportServerSiteSettingsGroupTitle; 
$Resources:ReportServerResources,ScheduleList; 
$Resources:ReportServerResources,SiteLevelSettings; 
$Resources:ReportServerResources,ManageSiteDataAlerts;
```

I tried to uninstall :

```
msiexec.exe /uninstall rsSharePoint.msi
```

it always says: not allowed/ not found

Any idea to resolve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, the issue occurs if you are in the Windows Powershell instead of the SharePoint Management Shell or the Reporting Services - SharePoint mode feature is not installed. So, please double check you are using the SharePoint Management Shell or install the Add-in by installing the rssharepoint.msi instead. Here is the download link:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35583

If it is not the issue, please install the Reporting Services - SharePoint mode from the SQL Server 2012 installation media.

Reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144289.aspx#bkmk_cmdlets_not_recognized

Comment: the solution was :install the Reporting Services - SharePoint mode from the SQL Server 2012 installation media.

Comment: good to know your issue resolved.